Next JS + Supabase: server side rendering not working
I have a very strange issue when using Next JS + Supabase.
Inside a server-side component, I'm creating a supabase server client as is done in the docs:
export function createClient() {
  const cookieStore = cookies()

  return createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return cookieStore.getAll()
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          try {
            cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
              cookieStore.set(name, value, options)
            )
          } catch {
            // The `setAll` method was called from a Server Component.
            // This can be ignored if you have middleware refreshing
            // user sessions.
          }
        },
      },
    }
  )
}

Of which I then use to get data from a table in supabase, by calling the below method:
export const getSubscription = cache(async (supabase: SupabaseClient) => {
  const { data: subscription, error } = await supabase
    .from('subscriptions')
    .select('*, prices(*, products(*))')
    .in('status', ['trialing', 'active'])
    .maybeSingle();

  return subscription;
});

My component looks like this:
export default async function Example() {
    const supabase = createClient();
    const subscription: Subscription = await getSubscription(supabase);
    console.log(subscription)

    return <div>Subscription status: {subscription.status}</div>
}

For some unknown reason, the contents of the component is not rendering on first load when running locally or in prod. I can log out the contents of subscription (as above) and I can see that the data is being successfully retrieved. But the  does not get rendered.
Locally, when I hot refresh, the div then renders fine.
The problem definitely appears to be with getSubscription(), as removing this stops the issue from happening. The issue is also happening with other methods that read from supabase tables (i.e. anything that calls supabase.from(), but doesn't happen when calling supabase.auth.getUser().
My middleware also looks exactly like what is suggested in the docs
The problem definitely appears to be with getSubscription(), as removing this stops the issue from happening. The issue is also happening with other methods that read from supabase tables (i.e. anything that calls supabase.from(), but doesn't happen when calling supabase.auth.getUser().
I've tried clearing browser cookies/cache.
I'm really stumped with this so would appreciate any help!
